# Adding Security to Swagger doesnt generate the equivalent json structure

Tags: java, swagger

Im using the ReaderListener to extend the definition of my swagger, I want to autogenerate the Security and SecurityDefinition in the json.

```
public class MagnetiseApiDefinition implements ReaderListener {
    public static final String SECURITY_NAME = "authentication";

    @Override
    public void beforeScan(Reader reader, Swagger swagger) {
        SecurityRequirement securityRequirement = new SecurityRequirement();
        List<String> scope = new ArrayList<>();
        scope.add("*");
        securityRequirement.setRequirements(SECURITY_NAME, scope);

        //Alternative1
        //List<SecurityRequirement> requirements = new ArrayList<>(1);
        //requirements.add(securityRequirement);
        //swagger.setSecurityRequirement(requirements);

        //Alternative2
        swagger.addSecurity(securityRequirement);

        ApiKeyAuthDefinition tokenScheme = new ApiKeyAuthDefinition();
        tokenScheme.setIn(In.HEADER);
        tokenScheme.setName("api_key");
        tokenScheme.setType("apiKey");
        swagger.addSecurityDefinition(SECURITY_NAME, tokenScheme);
    }
```

neither of the previous alternatives works, as they only generate:

```
"securityDefinitions" : {
    "authentication" : {
      "type" : "apiKey",
      "name" : "api_key",
      "in" : "header"
    }
  },
```

I checked the Swagger class and I found:

```
@Deprecated
public List<SecurityRequirement> getSecurityRequirement() {
    return security;
}

@JsonIgnore //remove JsonIgnore when getSecurityRequirement() method is deleted in next major version
public List<SecurityRequirement> getSecurity() {
    return security;
}
```

Any help? Cheers